# What do you call the the vertical spacing between 2 P block elements?

Tags: html, css

What do you the vertical spacing between html 2 P block element?  Are they margins?  But setting the margin to 0 of P elements does not completely eliminate the spacing? Negative margins eliminate the space but that does not seem to makes sense. It appears the rest of space is padding?

For example,

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Share the code that replicates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If the elements don't have a border, the *padding* may look like whitespace around the outside. Knowledge of the *box model* mount help you out here.

Comment: @Michael it's not a code problem, I just wanted to know what is that spacing called.  Just try any block elements they all have vertical spacing.

Comment: @theguy99 2 div's does not have any space between them, 2 `p` does, and that is a default margin

Comment: @LGSon Why the negative margin to eliminate it, not just 0 margin for elements?

Comment: @theguy99 no sir, there is no default margin, padding, or spacing on block elements by default. See exhibit a - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyZPmN There is sometimes a padding, margin, margin collapse, etc between 2 elements that could be causing whatever you're seeing. But unless you share the code, all we can do is guess and that isn't productive for anyone.

Comment: @theguy99 As suggested, post a code sample reproducing the issue you describe

Comment: @theguy99 https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/JNKPZG, you mean the body margin? white space around those div???

Comment: I'll reword my question,like LGsonsaid it 2 p does have space between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two `div`'s doesn't have any space between them, 2 `p` does, and that is a default margin, that some types of element have, like `p`, `h3` etc.

If one add a border to each of them, it is clear how it renders, and if to set the margin to 0, as done with the last two `p`'s, the space disappears.

That extra *inner* space, between the text and the border, belongs to the font and changes based on font size, as one can see is different in the `h3`

That *inner* font space can be somewhat controlled with `line-height`, as shown in the last two `div`'s

```css
div, p, h3 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

p ~ p ~ p {
  margin: 0;
}

div ~ div ~ div {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text in a div</div>
<div>Some text in a div</div>

<br>

<p>Some text in a p</p>
<p>Some text in a p</p>

<br>

<h3>Some text in a h3</h3>
<h3>Some text in a h3</h3>

<br>

<p>Some text in a p (has margin set to 0)</p>
<p>Some text in a p (has margin set to 0)</p>

<br>

<div>Some text in a div (that has line height)</div>
<div>Some text in a div (that has line height)</div>
```

Comment: p ~ p ~ p {
  margin: 0;
} did not eliminate spacing/margin?

Comment: @theguy99 Sibling selector `~`, to only target from the 3:rd and 4:th `p` so you see the difference

Comment: @theguy99 Updated my answer with some more info/samples

Answer (score 0):

You're correct -- the vertical (and horizontal) spacing between elements is the *margin*.  Removing all margins will remove all spacing between elements.  See the below example for how margins affect spacing:

```css
#box1 {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#box2 {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;  
}

#box3 {
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#box4 {
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;  
}
```

```html
<pre>margin: 0px;</pre>

<div id="box1">Box 1</div>

<div id="box2">Box 2</div>

<br><br>

<pre>margin: 5px;</pre>

<div id="box3">Box 3</div>

<div id="box4">Box 4</div>
```